# Add (1,2) shape of array to (1, 10, 2) shape of array. result (1, 11, 2)

Tags: python, arrays, append, reshape, np

```
A = [[2 , 3]]
A = np.array(A)
A.shape, A
shape A -> (1,2)
A -> array([[2, 3]])



B = [[[5, 7], [4, 8]]]
B = np.array(B)
B.shape -> (1, 2, 2)
B -> array([[[5, 7], 
             [4, 8]]]))
```

Now I want to append A to B.

The result should be the shape of -> (1, 3, 2)
The array should look like:

```
array([[[5, 7], 
        [4, 8],
        [2, 3]]]))
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.concatenate`. Sample code:

```py
np.concatenate([B, A[:,np.newaxis,:]], axis=1)
```

Result:

```
array([[[5, 7],
        [4, 8],
        [2, 3]]])
```